# presentation-api for ionic 7 capacitor5

Tags: ionic5, capacitor-plugin, presentation-api

I am looking for presentation-api under ionic 7.
I found related package, but

https://github.com/TheeMachine/presentation-capacitor <-- capacitor 5 do not support
https://github.com/fraunhoferfokus/cordova-plugin-presentation <-- It's too old version

My goal is to create a customer receipt screen (secondary screen) in POS.
Is there any other way? I heard that I should make two apps, but I don't understand.
I am using IMIN POS(https://www.imin.sg/en/imin-product-swan-1), and it has two tablets connected.
I don't know how to use the two apps.
presentation-api is the most appropriate method,
but if it is not supported,
I would like to look into other methods.
Thank you for your valuable reply.

My goal is to create a customer receipt screen (secondary screen) in POS

Comment: Thank you so much !!. I Solved at this post https://ionicj.com/presentation-api-ionic7-capacitor5-solution-android-only/